# Some problems with using semaphores

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore

Right now I'm working on my project and I have a question about initialization of semaphores. Actually I'm programming on Mac OS X, but I tried to compile me project on Linux and it doesn't compile. On OS X it compiles but every time just crashing at the moment of initialization.

```
sem_t *mutex_1, *mutex_2, *mutex_3, *reader, *writer;

int initialization_semaphores (void) 
{
    int ERROR = EOK;
    if ((mutex_1 = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        ERROR = ESEM;
    if ((mutex_2 = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        ERROR = ESEM;
    if ((mutex_3 = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        ERROR = ESEM;
    if ((reader = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        ERROR = ESEM;
    if ((writer = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        ERROR = ESEM;

    if (ERROR == EOK) {
        if (sem_init(mutex_1, 1, 1) == -1)
            ERROR = ESEM;
        if (sem_init(mutex_2, 1, 1) == -1)
            ERROR = ESEM;
        if (sem_init(mutex_3, 1, 1) == -1)
            ERROR = ESEM;
        if (sem_init(reader, 1, 1) == -1)
            ERROR = ESEM;
        if (sem_init(writer, 1, 1) == -1)
            ERROR = ESEM;
    }
}
```

When I tried to compile it on linux I see this:

```
/tmp/ccmkN9G7.o: In function `initialization_semaphores':
readerWriter.c:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `sem_init'
readerWriter.c:(.text+0x1cb): undefined reference to `sem_init'
readerWriter.c:(.text+0x1f4): undefined reference to `sem_init'
readerWriter.c:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `sem_init'
readerWriter.c:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to `sem_init'
readerWriter.c:(.text+0x275): undefined reference to `shm_open'
```

Is it right? :

```
int ERROR = EOK;
mutex_1 = sem_open("mutex1", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);   
mutex_2 = sem_open("mutex2", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);  
mutex_3 = sem_open("mutex3", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1); 
reader = sem_open("reader", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1); 
writer = sem_open("writer", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
```

Comment: I note you don't return a value from your function even though it is declared to return an `int`. This should have raised a warning -- did it raise any other warnings that might be useful? (Even though R.. is always correct, there might still be something enlightening in an error or warning.)

Comment: I returned the value form a function, actually I didn't paste here all of my function.

Comment: btw, errors and warnings are nearly impossible to read in comments; [edit]ing the post is probably better. :)

Comment: On Linux you probably need `-lpthread` and/or `-lrt`.

Comment: Yes I know about that but it doesn't work, I'm not able to init semaphores. Every time I'm getting ERROR = ESEM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mac OSX is non-conformant and does not support `sem_init`. The function exists but it silently fails or worse, leaving you with a non-working semaphore.

I'd encourage you to file a bug with Apple, since this is a real, long-standing problem that's affecting application portability badly. The more people who complain, the more hope there is of getting it fixed.

As for working around it, you can try to find/write a replacement implementation of all the POSIX semaphore functions and link your program to that, or you could switch to using `sem_open` instead of `mmap` and `sem_init`.

(As long as you're already going through the overhead of mapping a whole page for each semaphore, `sem_open` doesn't really cost you anything more. Where this bug is really a show-stopper is when you want to include your semaphores inside an existing `struct`.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround on Mac OSX.

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

typedef dispatch_semaphore_t sem_t;

void sem_init(sem_t* sem, bool is_pshared, unsigned value)
{
    *sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(value);
}

static void sem_destroy(sem_t* sem)
{
    dispatch_release(*sem);
}

static void sem_post(sem_t* sem)
{
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(*sem);
}

static void sem_wait(sem_t* sem)
{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(*sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

However, I don't know how to do `sem_getvalue()` -- if anyone knows, please let me know.